# Postgres query seems to return NaN as 0

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nan

I have a query in postgress which is as follows -

`select valuation from new_gcp.leads where valuation = 'NaN'`

and the result is as below -

[image]

I am wondering if `0` is NaN? or is it stored as `'0'` as string and that may be the reason? The data type of valuation column is `valuation NUMERIC(14,2)` and I am using `SQL Manager Lite for PostgreSQL` to run this query and view the result?

Comment: That is probably a setting of the tool you are using to see those rows. Try running the query in psql prompt, it should be displayed as `NaN`

Comment: What is the data type of the `valuation` column? What tool are you using to run this query and view the result?

Comment: Updated the question with details.